# Android:Can't connect to vpn server in android lollipop

Tags: android, vpn

the following code snippet is working fine in all android versions except lollipop version 5.0.2. I am not getting where i went wrong because code is working fine even with marsh mallow.

```
public synchronized boolean createTunnel(final VpnConfig config) throws Exception {
    InetSocketAddress server = new InetSocketAddress(config.address, Integer.parseInt(config.port));    
    mNetSocketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
    mNetSocketChannel.socket().setKeepAlive(true);

    // I am getting the problem here. This condition should not 
   //be true but in lollipop 5.0.2 it is giving the exception..
    if (!mService.protect(mNetSocketChannel.socket())) {
       // Protect the tunnel before connecting to avoid loopback.
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot protect the tunnel");
    }
    //mNetSocketChannel.socket().setSoTimeout(30);

    // Connect to the server.
    if (mNetSocketChannel.connect(server)) {
        mNetSocketChannel.configureBlocking(Utils.IS_TUNNEL_BLOCKING);

        if(config.isViaProxy){
            PrintLog.i(TAG, "Connecting via proxy.");
            configureOverProxy();
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain 'working fine' ? What's the problem in the lollipop version 5.0.2 with that code ?

Comment: in all other versions except lollipop I am able to connect to my server, but in this version i am getting exception which is can not protect the tunnel. and specially in motorola devices.